# no valid rapl domains found in package 0 : reboot after kali linux upgrade

Tags: boot, virtualbox, upgrade, kali-linux

I just performed `apt-get dist-upgrade` from `kali-2016.1`. After rebooting I got above error which is halting the boot process. I searched about this error and find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449574/intel-rapl-no-valid-rapl-domains-message-upon-boot) that my virtual environment (I am using `virtualBox Version 5.0.6 r103037`) is probably not supporting this power capping driver. I searched for VirtualBox support for it and found [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=63074) that it kind of doesn't need it, now I am stuck right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: That message is just a notice from the driver indicating that the CPU doesn't support the feature. That's not the reason your system wouldn't boot -- it just happened to be the last visible message before your box stopped booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution and posting if it could benefit someone else:

I searched and find out that many other people facing this problem with different Linux versions after an upgrade which I did, have checked the `Enable PAE/NX` checkbox in `System` settings of virtualBox. It was already checked, I uncheck it and start vm again, the error got passed but not enough to successful load. It now generated `Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes` and halted again. I recheck the checkbox mentioned previously and again start, same second error. I pressed Alt+F2, started a new terminal, typed `apt-get -f install` [to find all broken dependencies], it gave me an error during `unpackaging vlc***.deb` file. I purged all vlc data by `apt-get purge vlc`, shutdown and restart again and now it has been loaded successfully.

PS:
One more thing I also unchecked `Enable 3D Accelaration` in Display settings of virtualBox